# Java bytecode to class

Tags: java, transform, bytecode

I get byte code from network. I transform byte array to class

```
package l2soft.utils;

public final class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

public static CustomClassLoader _instance;
public static CustomClassLoader getInstance() {
    return _instance;
}

public void defineCustomClass(byte[] bytecode) {
    Class<?> clazz = defineClass(null, bytecode, 0, bytecode.length);
    resolveClass(clazz);
}

}
```

but when the application starts, derived classes can not be found.

```
The import test.Test1 cannot be resolved
```

(compilled with recieved class)

note: i don't know class file name. I do not need to request a class, the server itself sends

UPD:

```
package l2soft.utils;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public final class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

    private Map<String, Class<?>> cache;

    public static CustomClassLoader _instance;
    public static CustomClassLoader getInstance() {
        return _instance;
    }

    public CustomClassLoader(ClassLoader parent) {
        super(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
        _instance = this;
        cache = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();
    }

    public void defineCustomClass(byte[] bytecode) {
        Class<?> clazz = defineClass(null, bytecode, 0, bytecode.length);
        resolveClass(clazz);
        cache.put(clazz.getName(), clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class<?> result = cache.get(name);

        if(result == null)
            super.findClass(name);

        return result;
    }

}
```

It is my custom classloader. SomeClass load by this classloader and tes.Test1. But i see error: import test.Test1 cannot resolve. This CustomClassLoader set as default loader (-Djava system.loader=l2soft.utils.CustomClassLoader)

Comment: Are you downloading all the required classes or just the one?

Comment: `-verbose:class` is your friend in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't specify in your question, I'll assume that you're importing `test.Test1` in a class named `SomeClass`. I also assume that this class is in your initial classpath when you run the JVM (this seems to be implied by the nature of the problem).

When your application starts, it will load all the classes on the classpath (including `SomeClass`) using the default class loader. To ensure that `SomeClass` can operate properly, it has to also ensure that all the other classes that it imports (including `test.Test1`) are also loaded.

The problem is, since `test.Test1` **isn't** on the classpath, the default class loader can't resolve it, hence the error. `test.Test1` is not resolvable until after you manually load it with your custom loader, which occurs **after** the initial class load from the class path (when the application is actually run by the JVM).

This is probably not an easy thing to fix. Probably the easiest approach is to make `test.Test1` implement some interface (say `Test`) which **is** on the classpath. Then, in `SomeClass` you can import `Test` and use `Test` references rather than `test.Test1` references to refer to objects of your dynamically loaded class.

Comment: SomeClass load after test.Test1 class. I try use my CustomClassLoader as system (-Djava.system.loader) and override findClass with cache, but result is not changed.

Comment: If, as you say, `SomeClass` is loaded after you load `test.Test1`, then probably either `test.Test1` isn't actually being loaded properly, or the loader that loads `SomeClass` is different to the one that loads `test.Test1` and is not its descendant (hence, `test.Test1` is loaded but not in the class hierarchy `SomeClass` has access to). Also, I believe that's `-Djava.system.class.loader`, not `-Djava.system.loader`.